# How to update contact details using Microsoft Graph API in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Hi I am new to Objective C and Microsoft's Graph API and would to know how we can update a contact details such as job title, number, photo for Office 365 using the Outlook API.

Right now I am only able to retrieve contacts from the directory using code examples provided on GitHub. Help highly appreciated.

I am looking at:
http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/contact_update

Comment: That is the right link for personal contacts documentation. Are you getting an error when trying to update it?

Comment: I don't know how to write the methods in objective c to update a user's contact detail. I made a bit of progress and have found these code snippets though: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-iOS-Snippets

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the graph client, lets say it's at self.graphClient, 
you should be able to do

```
[[[[self.graphClient me] contacts:@"ID"] request] update:msGraphContactObject withCompletion:^(MSGraphContact *response, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

For more up to date sample, please visit

- [objective-c snippets sample using graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ios-objectiveC-snippets-sample)
- [swift sample using graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ios-swift-snippets-sample)